# R aggregate list of dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum, aggregate-functions

I do have a list of 53 data frames (purchase01 to purchase53), ordered by date, with 18 variables and distinct number of rows (tryed, but coulden't paste a example on the following).  I want to *aggregate* each distinct data frame by its repeated values of "V9"- factor- by sum the column "V2"- numeric. I coulden't find the answer yet.

For only one dataframe I can use 
`aggregate.data.frame(purchase00$V12, by = list(purchase00($V9),FUN = sum)` and itjust works fine.

I tryed llply, 
`llply(.data = purchase, .fun = aggregate.data.frame, by= list(unique((V9),sum, .inform = TRUE)`

but without sucess, it seems that the function does not receive the by for every dataframe nor the function sum. Also the mapply didn't work well for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
## assuming your list is called list_of_df
require(dplyr)

summarized_list <- lapply(list_of_df,  function(x) {

x %>% group_by(V9) %>% summarize(sum(V2))

})
```

This will return a list with the summary of each data frame in your purchase list.

If you don't want to use `dplyr` , you can do this with base :

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) {aggregate(values ~ day_of_week, data = x, sum) })
```

Comment: the dplyr  gavte me a sumaraized data, in the case I needed the output without sommirize it. The lapply just worked fine.
Thank you