# Aggregate variables in list of data frames into single data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, sum, aggregate-functions

I am performing a per policy life insurance valuation in R. Monthly cash flow projections are performed per policy and returns a data frame in the following format (for example):

```
Policy1 = data.frame(ProjM = 1:200,
                     Cashflow1 = rep(5,200),
                     Cashflow2 = rep(10,200))
```

My model returns a list (using lapply and a function which performs the per policy cashflow projection - based on various per policy details, escalation assumptions and life contingencies). I want to aggregate the cash flows across all policies by `ProjM`. The following code does what I want, but looking for a more memory efficient way (ie not using the `rbindlist` function). Example data:

```
Policy1 = data.frame(ProjM = 1:5,
                     Cashflow1 = rep(5,5),
                     Cashflow2 = rep(10,5))

Policy2 = data.frame(ProjM = 1:3,
                     Cashflow1 = rep(50,3),
                     Cashflow2 = rep(-45,3))

# this is the output containing 35000 data frames:
ListOfDataFrames = list(Policy1 = Policy1, Policy2 = Policy2)
```

My code:

```
library(data.table)
OneBigDataFrame <- rbindlist(ListOfDataFrames)
MyOutput <- aggregate(. ~ ProjM, data = OneBigDataFrame, FUN = sum)
```

Output required:

```
ProjM Cashflow1 Cashflow2
 1        55       -35
 2        55       -35
 3        55       -35
 4         5        10
 5         5        10
```

I have looked for examples, and [R aggregate list of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567653/r-aggregate-list-of-dataframe) performs aggregation for all data frames, but do not combine them into 1 data frame.

Comment: Do you want to _avoid_ to create one big data.frame with all your _input_ data because of memory constraints but have the aggregated values in one _output_ data.table?  BTW: If you are using `data.table` already, why don't you continue with `data.table` syntax for aggregation?

Comment: I have found my best solution by using matrices instead: 
`ListOfMatrices = list(Policy1 = as.matrix(Policy1), Policy2 = as.matrix(Policy2))` 
`OneBigMatrix = do.call(rbind,ListOfMatrices)` 
`MyOutputNew = rowsum(OneBigMatrix[,2:3], group = OneBigMatrix[,1])` 

The `MyOutputNew` does not have the `ProjM`, but primarily i want to work with `Cashflow1` and `Cashflows2`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table` syntax the one step approach would be to create the big data.table first and then do the aggregation:

```
library(data.table)
OneBigDataFrame <- rbindlist(ListOfDataFrames)
OneBigDataFrame[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM]
```

or, more concise

```
rbindlist(ListOfDataFrames)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM]
```

> ```
>    ProjM Cashflow1 Cashflow2
> 1:     1        55       -35
> 2:     2        55       -35
> 3:     3        55       -35
> 4:     4         5        10
> 5:     5         5        10
> ```

Now, the OP has requested to avoid creating the big data.table first in order to save memory. This requires a two step approach where the aggregates are computed for each data.table which are then aggregated to a grand total in the final step:

```
rbindlist(
  lapply(ListOfDataFrames, 
         function(x) setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM])
  )[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM]
```

> ```
>    ProjM Cashflow1 Cashflow2
> 1:     1        55       -35
> 2:     2        55       -35
> 3:     3        55       -35
> 4:     4         5        10
> 5:     5         5        10
> ```

Note that `setDT()` is used here to coerce the data.frames to data.table *by reference*, i.e., without creating an additional copy which saves time and memory.

#### Benchmark

Using the benchmark data [of d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45086230/3817004) (list of 10000 data.frames with 100 rows each, 28.5 Mb in total) with all answers provided so far:

```
mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  malan = {
    OneBigDataFrame <- rbindlist(test)
    malan <- aggregate(. ~ ProjM, data = OneBigDataFrame, FUN = sum)
  },
  d.b = d.b <- with(data = data.frame(do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, test)),
             expr = aggregate(x = list(Cashflow1 = Cashflow1, Cashflow2 = Cashflow2),
                              by = list(ProjM = ProjM),
                              FUN = sum)),
  a.gore = {
    newagg <- function(dataset) { 
      dataset <- data.table(dataset)
      dataset <- dataset[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=ProjM,.SDcols=c("Cashflow1","Cashflow2")]
      return(dataset)
    }
    a.gore <- newagg(rbindlist(lapply(test,newagg)))
  },
  dt1 = dt1 <- rbindlist(test)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM],
  dt2 = dt2 <- rbindlist(
    lapply(test, 
           function(x) setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM])
  )[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ProjM],
  times = 5L
)
mb
```

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval  cld
>   malan   565.43967   583.08300   631.15898   600.45790   605.60237   801.2120     5  b  
>     d.b   707.50261   710.31127   719.25591   713.54526   721.26691   743.6535     5  b  
>  a.gore 14706.40442 14747.76305 14861.61641 14778.88547 14805.29412 15269.7350     5    d
>     dt1    40.10061    40.92474    42.27034    41.55434    42.07951    46.6925     5 a   
>     dt2  8806.85039  8846.47519  9144.00399  9295.29432  9319.17251  9452.2275     5   c
> ```

The fastest solution is the one step approach using `data.table` which is 15 times faster than the second fastest. Surprisingly, the two step `data.table` approaches are magnitudes slower than the one step approach.

To make sure that all solutions return the same result this can be checked using

```
all.equal(malan, d.b)
all.equal(malan, as.data.frame(a.gore))
all.equal(malan, as.data.frame(dt1))
all.equal(malan, as.data.frame(dt2))
```

which return `TRUE` in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution might be efficient. Give it a try and let me know

```
require(data.table)
newagg <- function(dataset) { dataset <- data.table(dataset);dataset <- dataset[,lapply(.SD,sum),by=ProjM,.SDcols=c("Cashflow1","Cashflow2")]; return(dataset)}
newagg(rbindlist(lapply(ListOfDataFrames,newagg)))
# ProjM Cashflow1 Cashflow2
# 1:     1        55       -35
# 2:     2        55       -35
# 3:     3        55       -35
# 4:     4         5        10
# 5:     5         5        10
```